# ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 50, 200, 200]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was wondering if someone can help me understand my dimension mismatch here. I am training a NER model, where the input are sentences, padded to a word length of 50, where each word its GloVe 200 representation. targets are a one-hot encoding of 7 classes.

X_train shape is (9358, 50, 200)
y_train shape is (9358, 50, 7)

Before switching to word embeddings, my input was just a word2idx representation from my vocab, and so the dimensions were only (9358, 50) for X, and my model worked fine.

```
def fit(x_train, y_train, num_words, tags, embeddings_matrix):
    max_length = 50
    embedding_dim = 200
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_words, output_dim=200, 
                    input_length=max_length, weights=[embeddings_matrix], mask_zero=True))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_dim, return_sequences=True, 
                             recurrent_dropout=0.01)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(tags))))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()

    print(x_train.shape)
    print(y_train.shape)

    history = model.fit(
        x_train, 
        y_train,
        validation_split = 0.2,
        batch_size = 64,
        epochs = 20,
        verbose = 1
    )

    return model
```

I have tried a few different constructions, like setting Input(shape=(50,200,)) that I pass in, put haven't had any success with anything. I am just confused why another dimension of length 200 is being added through the embedding layer that is causing all the problems

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already encoded the input to GloVe 200, then why do you need the `Embedding` layer? I believe that's what's adding the extra dimension, which is causing the error.